# how to insert data into query string on angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i want to put this data {{wilayahAsal.namaWilayah}} into query string ...

```
<select class="kotaAsal" id="kotaAsal" name="kotaAsal"  style="width: 200px;" ng-model="id_wilAsal" ng-change="fetch()">
                                                <optgroup ng-repeat="list_kota_asal in _result_kota_asal" label="{{list_kota_asal.namaProvinsi}}">
                                                    <option ng-repeat="wilayahAsal in list_kota_asal.wilayahs" value="{{wilayahAsal.idWilayah}}">
                                                        {{wilayahAsal.namaWilayah}}
                                                    </option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
```

and this is button click

```
<input type="button" value="Cari" ng-click="panggil(form, wilayahAsal.namaWilayah)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary form-control">
```

and this is controller

```
  $scope.panggil = function(form, wilayahAsal, wilayahTujuan){

$scope['wilayahAsal'] = wilayahAsal;
console.log($scope['wilayahAsal']);

$scope['wilayahTujuan'] = wilayahTujuan;
console.log($scope['wilayahTujuan']);
};
```

but the result is undefined... but the result is undefined ... how to make the value (text) appear?

Comment: `wilayahTujuan` will be **undefined** because you only pass two parameters in your panggil function.

Comment: I also input it into a select

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select class="kotaAsal" id="kotaAsal" name="kotaAsal" ng-model="wilayahAsal.namaWilayah" style="width: 200px;" ng-change="fetch()">
<optgroup ng-repeat="list_kota_asal in _result_kota_asal" label="{{list_kota_asal.namaProvinsi}}">
<option ng-repeat="wilayahAsal in list_kota_asal.wilayahs" value="{{wilayahAsal.idWilayah}}">
  {{wilayahAsal.namaWilayah}}
</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
           
<input type="button" value="Cari" ng-click="panggil(form, wilayahAsal.namaWilayah,wilayahAsal.namaWilayah)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary form-control">

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope._result_kota_asal = [
        {
         "namaProvinsi":"Pro",
         "wilayahs": [{
            "idWilayah":1,
         "namaWilayah":"John"
          }]
        }
         ];
                              
$scope.panggil = function(form, wilayahAsal, wilayahTujuan){

angular.forEach($scope._result_kota_asal, function(value, key) {
if(value.wilayahs[0].idWilayah == wilayahAsal)
{
 $scope['wilayahAsal'] = value.wilayahs[0].namaWilayah;
}
 });
console.log('wilayahAsal',$scope['wilayahAsal']);

$scope['wilayahTujuan'] = wilayahTujuan;
console.log('wilayahTujuan',$scope['wilayahTujuan']);
};
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to make that appear is namawilayah, not idwilayah? Because I want namawilayah will show

Comment: but... that data get from value, whether the data can be obtained from the contents of the option {{wiilayahAsal.namaWilayah}}?  not from <option value="{{wilayahAsal.namaWilayah}}">

Comment: you can get namaWilayah based on idWilayah from controller itself using angular.forEach (see the edited code)